How does the central server know how to send the message to the other client?
I have been learning as a hobbyist about NAT Traversal using the RFC and I am confused about how relaying would work. Let's say I have a centralized server on DigitalOcean, hosted on a public address. And I have two machines I want to establish a p2p connection with. I understand that NATs would translate my private IP to a public IP and hence the central server would have my public IP via some kind of UDP state? The same connection can be done with the other NATed host I want to communicate to. So, in my understanding, the centralized server now has some kind of state about the two IPs of both hosts? Now, my questions are,

If I want to communicate with the other NATed host, how would I send the first request because I still do not know the public IP?
Does the relay server have to communicate the public IP of the other NATed host to me?
Does the other party just have to write to the UDP connection established on the other side? Hence it has to know which port is opened to the other NATed host?


Some answers :

If I want to communicate with the other NATed host, how would I send the first request because I still do not know the public IP?

The server never initiates access to any client. The client does the
connecting and the answer comes back over the established connection.
If the two computers are behind the same router, both will have the
same public IP. The router has no problem or need to distinguish between
the two, as it is just a pipe for the connection.

Does the relay server have to communicate the public IP of the other NATed host to me?

Any relay server does not modify the source IP address in the message
that it passes on. The server will know the originating IP address,
but has no need to know the IP addresses of all the relay computers
or networks.

Does the other party just have to write to the UDP connection established on the other side? Hence it has to know which port is opened to the other NATed host?

Source and destination ports are specified in the message, so are known
to the server.
Have a look at the message formats in the following references :

Wikipedia Transmission Control Protocol
Wikipedia User Datagram Protocol

